# node attribute containing Chef server URL?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, ohai-gem

Would Chef server URL be accessible as an attribute of a node? I would like to have a custom recipe behaviour changed based on the server id (URL) the node is connected to.

https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html doesn't list server (URL) provided.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chef_server_url` [config setting](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) is not available as a node attribute, but you can access this configuration via `Chef::Config`:

```
Chef::Config['chef_server_url']
```

Comment: the nodes in my chef server seem to have an attribute for it at node['chef_client']['config']['chef_server_url'] but that may be because I use the chef-client cookbook as part of my base cookbook runlist.

Comment: Yes, sure, if you're using the [chef-client](supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook, you can also use the info form there. Depends on the environment, of course.